# How does std::string allocate memory in GCC with -fwhole-program?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

**Update:** The following problem appears to depend on the `-fwhole-program` option.

I've been playing around a bit with memory allocation, and I encountered a small mystery: In GCC (4.6), how does `std::string` allocate its memory [*edit*]when I compile with `-fwhole-program`[/]?

Have this following test program:

```
#include <new>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void * operator new(std::size_t n) throw(std::bad_alloc)
{
  void * const p = std::malloc(n);

  if (p == NULL) throw std::bad_alloc();

  std::cerr << "new() requests " << n << " bytes, allocated at " << p << ".\n";

  return p;
}

void operator delete(void * p) noexcept
{
  std::cerr << "delete() at " << p << ".\n";
  std::free(p);
}

int main()
{
  std::string s = "Hello world.";
}
```

When I use any other dynamic container (which uses `std::allocator<T>`), the allocator uses `::operator new`, and so I see the debug messages happily. However, with `std::string`, I see nothing at all. I'm sure that dynamic allocation happens, though, as I can confirm with valgrind (13 plus string length bytes are allocated). I went through several source files and the standard, and I'm pretty sure that the template is `std::basic_string<T, std::char_traits<T>, std::allocator<T>>`, so I'm at a loss why I don't see the messages from my replaced allocation functions.

Can anyone shed any light on this conundrum? What do I do to track string allocations? Also, could anyone run this through some other compiler and see if it produces any output?

(For example: if I add `std::map<int, int> m { { 0, 1 } };`, I have output `new() requests 24 bytes, allocated at 0x8d53028` etc.)

Comment: Beware of the small buffer optimization.

Comment: Update: The problem only appears (in GCC 4.6.1 and 4.4.3) if I compile with `-fwhole-program`!

Comment: FWIW: I'm getting output from your custom new using 64-bit g++ 4.5.2, in debug or optimize mode.

Comment: @David: Right, thanks. Can you try it with `-fwhole-program`?

Comment: FWIW Visual Studio 2010 in a debug build does call operator new.  Any optimization enabled?  Trace through the execution and see what's happening.

Comment: @GuySirton: Yes, I just discovered that this is due to the `-fwhole-program` compiler option in GCC. I suppose it's a bug somewhere, unless there's a reason why this should be a permissible optimization. I might close this question, though, since this is now much more specific than I thought it would be.

Comment: Kerrek, I have tried it with VS2010 too, and have actually reproduced your (initial) findings. When the string was less than 16 chars long, an internal 16 chars array was been used instead of a `new`. When the string was larger, your `operator new` was called. Was using both debug and release builds.

Comment: @eran: Cool, thanks. Yes, VS2010 has some clever small-string optimizations, that's good to know. GCC doesn't have those as far as I can tell.

Comment: Problem reproduced with a snapshot of GCC 4.7.

Comment: I've posted a [bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50594), and some people suggested it has something to do with `string` being part of the compiled library...

Comment: The discussion attendant to the [bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50594) seems to have revealed the source of the problem: `-fwhole-program` makes all functions `static`, but having a static allocation function is ill-formed. There's a GCC-specific workaround with `__attribute__((externally_visible))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the output of `g++ ... -S` with / without `-fwhole-program` it appears that the whole custom new/delete operators aren't emitted at all when using `fwhole-program`.

I'm starting to suspect we're looking at a bug here.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I'll file this as a bug, and we can see if any of the developers can confirm this.

Comment: It's strange though that with any other container the operator *does* get used!