# Dead code removal if implementation is overwritten

Tags: c, c99, dead-code

I'm in the process of writing a library that provides a sha256 implementation. The library will be given to vendors that may want to provide their own sha256 functions that are optimized for their platform. So, the API of this library allows the client to pass in function pointers to their sha256 code.

```
int mylib_set_sha256_impl( /* function pointers */ );
```

Henceforth, all algorithms will use the function pointers provided internally instead of the stock sha256 code provided by the library.

**The question is:** how can I facilitate dead code removal during link time, such that the default sha256 implementation in this library is removed??

This is an API design question as much as it is a compiler-optimization question.

Comment: Maybe look into [weak aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525537/what-are-practical-applications-of-weak-linking).

Comment: Is weak aliasing something that is supported by the major compiler vendors (ie, MSVC, gcc, clang, Intel C...)

Comment: Definitely GCC, the others probably too.

Comment: I will investigate this. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Usually, it'll be the linker, not the compiler, that deals with that. But yeah, all mainstream linkers support it.

Comment: If the user-provided function pointers will be resolved at runtime (by the call to the API), I think it unlikely that the linker will be able to omit the default implementation.

Comment: It seems that dynamic linkage might break the weak aliasing approach...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no special requirement as far as linker is concerned, and no weak aliasing need be considered.

The basic rule is: As long as the user code doesn't reference any symbols in a given `.c` or `.s` file that you linked into your library, the said file's contents won't end up in the executable.

In the scenario you describe, your functions may never become dead code since your "live" code perhaps references their addresses to set up default function pointer values. To make sure that doesn't happen, you have to do the following:

1. Refer to the replaceable functions only from within a user-callable *optional* `default_init` function.
2. The `default_init` must never be called anywhere in your code, neither must any of the functions be referenced anywhere but within `default_init`.
3. Have the replaceable functions, and the init function, put into at least one  `.c` or assembly file that is not used for any of the other code.

For your user to replace *all* the functions, they simply have to never call the `default_init` function. If you wish functions to be replaceable one-by-one, you have to, additionally:

1. Have each replaceable function in its own `.c` file.
2. Have the user not call the `default_init` directly, but pass the desired default or user-provided implementations to your `init` function.

What you're doing, in effect, isn't "overwriting" any implementation, but simply not using it at all.

Example (include guards omitted for clarity):

```
// api.h
void api_fun1(void);
void api_fun2(void);
void api_default_init(void);
void api_user_init(void (*f1)(void), void (*f2)(void));
void api_use_funs(void);

// api_internal.h
extern void (*api_f1)(void);
extern void (*api_f2)(void);    

// common.c
#include "api.h"
#include "api_internal.h"
void (*api_f1)(void);
void (*api_f2)(void);

void api_user_init(void (*f1)(void), void (*f2)(void)) {
  api_f1 = f1;
  api_f2 = f2;
}

void api_use_funs(void) {
  api_f1();
  api_f2();
}

// api_fun1.c
#include "api.h"
void api_fun1(void) {}

// api_fun2.c
#include "api.h"
void api_fun2(void) {}

// api_default_init.c
#include "api.h"
#include "api_internal.h"

void api_default_init(void) {
  api_f1 = api_fun1;
  api_f2 = api_fun2;
}
```

Let's say that the user wants to override `api_fun2` with their own:

```
// main.c
#include "api.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void my_fun2() {
  printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

int main() {
  api_user_init(api_fun1, my_fun2);
  api_use_funs();
}
```

Comment: I've basically came to this conclusion. Having a `set_sha256_defaults()` is fine, but my library in question has many such overrides (ie. other hash implementations, RNG, HMAC, CRC, etc.) which will litter the API with a bunch of `*_defaults()` functions. I was hoping to a more elegant solution, but it's starting to look as if one might not be better than the one you posted.

Comment: The only "elegance" would be that the default functions wouldn't have the `_default` suffix. Otherwise, the use of the weak symbols gives only one advantage: you don't need to use function pointers at all. A user-provided function with the same name would simply override yours. I'm ambivalent as to whether it's a good thing or not.