# Shall external "C" enclose the declaration or definition of a C++ function?

Tags: c++, c

I  saw in a cpp file that `external "C" {...}` encloses the definitions of several functions.

From https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp, I guess the purpose of using `extern "C"` in the cpp file is to make the enclosed C++ functions available to be used in a C  program.

The example in the link shows that `extern "C"` encloses the declarations of the C++ functions only, not their definitions

> Just declare the C++ function extern "C" (in your C++ code) and call
>   it (from your C or C++ code). For example:
>
> ```
>     // C++ code:
>     extern "C" void f(int);
>     void f(int i)
>     {
>         // ...
>     }
> ```

The cpp file I mentioned at the beginning looks like instead:

```
    // C++ code:
    extern "C" {

    void f(int i)
    {
        // ...
    }

    void g(int i)
    {
        // ...
    }

    }
```

Shall `extern "C"` enclose the declarations or definitions of C++ functions? 
If so, why?

Comment: @Alex It doesn't really _change the ABI_, just the name mangling.

Comment: Remeber that definition is a declaration too, **[dcl.link] 7.5/6** migh be of interest.

Comment: In the first case, the second function f is not using C-naming linkage. You can check this by dumping the symbol of the produced object.

Comment: @xryl669 If it doesn't, you have a compiler bug.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ` "just the name mangling" 7.5/1 "a particular language linkage may be associated with a particular form of representing names of objects and functions with external linkage (mangling---n.m.), or with a particular calling convention (ABI---n.m.)". "Two function types with different language linkages are distinct types even if they are otherwise identical."  5.2.2 "Calling a function through an expression whose function type has a language linkage that is different from
the language linkage of the function type of the called function’s definition is undefined".

Answer (score 16):

It should enclose the declarations in the header file, and definitions should be enclosed as long the translation unit is compiled using the c++ compiler, and as long the declaration wasn't seen there.
It's never wrong doing both in c++ code.

If the c compiler is used to compile the function definitions, it's not necessary (or should I better to say would be wrong syntax, see the note below).

`extern "C" {}` scopes control that plain c symbols linkage is used for everything inside. Otherwise [**c++ name mangling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) would be applied.

---

Note:

Since `extern "C" {}` this isn't valid c syntax, to make that working with the c compiler, you'll need to use it within `#ifdef`:

**`MyHeader.h`:**

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif

 // ... c style function name declarations
 void foo(int i);

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 } // extern "C"
 #endif
```

---

### The use of the `extern "C" {}` scope is actually twofold:

---

#### Exporting C++ code to C

If the above is compiled with the c compiler, it appears for it as a normal c function declaration. If compiled with the c++ compiler the `extern` keyword applies and the c++ name mangling will be suppressed.

Regarding the definition, the function can use any c++ features inside it's definition:

```
 extern "C" {
     void foo(int x) {
         std::vector v(x);
         // ... blah, more c++ stuff
     }
 }
```

Note that the declaration wasn't included here. This can be used as a technique, particularly useful when you want to override functions exposed from a library for [*weak linkage*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525537/what-are-practical-applications-of-weak-linking).

In case of including the `MyHeader.h`, the `extern "C" {}` scope can be omitted.

---

#### Importing C code from C++

If the above declaration is seen in the c++ compiler, again c++ name mangling is suppressed, and any call reference to `foo()` wil be resolved by the linker using a plain c function symbol name:

```
  #include "MyHeader.h"
  class MyClass {
  public:
       void bar(int y) {
           // Use foo() as plain c function:
           foo(y);
       }
  };
```

The `foo()` function implementation is provided from an object file (or archive) that was created using the c compiler.

Comment: Thanks. Is `#ifdef` used when calling C++ code in a C program, or when calling C code in a C++ program?

Comment: @Tim The `#ifdef` refers to the c compiler, as mentioned c doesn't understand that syntax. The uses of `extern` are either to import code compiled with the c compiler to c++, or to export code compiled with the c++ compiler to c.

Comment: Thanks. Just a somehow non-related question, is `#ifdef` recognizable by a C++ compiler? In other words, does a C++ compiler also use the directives used in a C compiler?

Comment: @Tim Sure the directive will evaluate to true ***exclusively*** in the c++ compiler. Don't confuse the c-preprocessor with the compiler language variants.

Comment: @Tim Updated the answer, I hope this clarifies all your doubts how `extern "C" {}` actually works.

Comment: "and definitions should be enclosed" citation needed.

Comment: @n.m. In the sub sentence: _"as long the translation unit is compiled using the c++ compiler, and as long the declaration wasn't seen there."_. No citation needed, since these need to be _self contained_. Isn't that clear?

Comment: Sorry didn't see this passage.

Comment: "plain c name mangling is used for everything inside" -- better to say "C language linkage", since the standard permits the calling convention to be different as well as just the name mangling.

Comment: @SteveJessop You are my escape <3. I didn't know how to name that correctly (since c doesn't provide any _name mangling_ at alll actually).

Answer (score 8):

[dcl.link]/5:

> Except for functions with C++ linkage, a function declaration without
>   a linkage specification shall not precede the first linkage
>   specification for that function. A function can be declared without a
>   linkage specification after an explicit linkage specification has been
>   seen; the linkage explicitly specified in the earlier declaration is
>   not affected by such a function declaration.

Both versions are fine as far as the language linkage of the function is concerned. The important part is that the first declaration of the function must have `extern "C"` on it.

Comment: So this effectively means, if a function was declared within the `extern "C" {}` scope before, the definition will refer to this declaration regardless it was compiled as c++ or c code?`

Answer (score 3):

Better should include both.

To make sure that symbol is not mangled when we link a C code in C++. we use extern "C" block.

Whenever some code is put in extern “C” block, C++ compiler ensures that the function names are unmangled i.e compiler generate a binary file with their names unchanged, as C compiler will do.

[Mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) As C++ supports function overloading, so basically there can be more than one function with same name. So to distinguish between different functions when it generates object code – it changes names by adding information about arguments. Technique of adding additional information to function names is called Name Mangling.

As C does not support function overloading. So we use extern 'C' block while linking C code in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose both declarations and definitions. "C" and "C++" functions are exported with different names. To produce correct "C" external name in object file `extern "C"` is needed in cpp, otherwise function will be exported with [C++ name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) . You also need to enclose those `extern "C" {` and corresponding `}` into `#ifdef __cplusplus` and `#endif` in header file, which is going to be #included by a C project to avoid C compilation error

Comment: `extern "C"` is not necessary before definitions; it's only necessary before declarations. If the definition precedes the declaration (according to best practices; not an absolute requirement), the mangling will adjust to declaration.

Comment: @anatolyg I just recently fixed linker error in some project caused by exactly this thing - function was exported from a library with C+ name mangling and therefore could not be used in plain C project. Despite the fact that the same header (with "extern "C" ) was used for DLL compilation

Answer (score -2):

In the [same document](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#c-calls-cpp), it shows a code example that has `extern "C"` in the declaration, but not in the definition.

If your definition "sees" the declaration (that is, the declaration precedes the definition in the translation unit), you *don't* need `extern "C"` on the definition. But it won't hurt - it will be silently ignored by the compiler.

Here is the code example given in the FAQ:

```
// This is C++ code
// Declare f(int,char,float) using extern "C":
extern "C" void f(int i, char c, float x);
// ...
// Define f(int,char,float) in some C++ module:
void f(int i, char c, float x)
{
  // ...
}
```

If you, for any reason, decide not to include the declaration before your definition, you *have to* provide the `extern "C"` modifier:

```
// This is C++ code
// Define f(int,char,float) in some C++ module:
extern "C" void f(int i, char c, float x)
{
  // ...
}
```

However, this goes against most style guidelines of C and C++.