# Wrapping a C header

Tags: c++, wrapper

I need to make a wrapper for a C header, in such a way that none of the functions from that header can be visible outside this wrapper.

The first thing that came to my mind was to use a namespace in the `include`, but it didn't work, as expected, due to C++ mangling, like so:

```
namespace wrap {
    extern "C" {
        #include<a/b/c_header.h>
}};
```

This will give me errors like: `cannot convert 'wrap::some_type*' to 'some_type*' for argument # from __some_inner_function`, which I find very annoying because both types are actually the same.

This header has hundreds of functions which I'm currently using in my code, so wrapping one by one might not be feasible, in particular because it is not something so trivial to be solved with a few `sed`'s.

I'm afraid that this has no solution, and that I would simply have to accept that all functions from those headers will have global scope.

I wondered if I could make some fancy macros to help me on this, but I couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: Did you miss a `using wrap;`?

Comment: What do you need to wrap the header for if you're going to hide the entire surface from all consumers?

Comment: What is the purpose of "wrapping" the header? C headers work just fine (mostly) in C++.

Comment: What is preventing some other C++ source from directly including the C header file? What is forcing them to use your wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to hide a C function and expose an equivalent C++ function is to declare the C++ function, and have it call the C function.

```
extern "C" int c_function (int);

namespace wrap {
    int c_function (int arg) {
        return ::c_function(arg);
    }
}
```

If your C interface uses variable arguments, you may want to use a C++ template to wrap the call instead. If C++ 11 is not available to you, then it may not be possible to properly wrap that interface unless the C interface provides an alternate version of the function that accepts a `va_list` parameter.

```
extern "C" int c_function_var_args (int, ...);
extern "C" int c_function_va_list (int, va_list);

namespace wrap {
#if defined(HAVE_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES)
    template <typename... Types>
    int c_function_var_args (int arg, Types... rest_args) {
        return ::c_function_var_args(arg, rest_args...);
    }
#else
    int c_function_var_args (int arg, ...) {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, arg);
        int r = ::c_function_va_list(arg, ap);
        va_end(ap);
        return r;
    }
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The attempt to wrap a header using

```
namespace wrap {
    extern "C" {
        #include<a/b/c_header.h>
}};
```

is pretty useless, since `extern "C" {}` forces c-style name mangling for everything declared inside that scope.

You should drop the `extern "C" {}` stuff, to have c++ compliant symbol resolution for the declarations appearing inside the namespace.

Also see this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927388/shall-external-c-enclose-the-declaration-or-definition-of-a-c-function/37927500?s=2|0.0000#37927500) for detailed explanation what `extern "C"` actually does.

Comment: Is it so useless that it's namespace std { extern "C" strlen(const char *s); } ? Note that if this is a C header, it won't work without the extern "C"

Comment: @Joshua `extern "C"` actually prevents adoption to a c++ namespace, but forces c-style function name mangling.