# glibc uses kernel functions

Tags: c

I am trying to understand this method from the glibc source code:

```
    26 #if LIBM_SVID_COMPAT
    27 /* wrapper sqrtf */
    28 float
    29 __sqrtf (float x)
    30 {
    31   if (__builtin_expect (isless (x, 0.0f), 0) && _LIB_VERSION     != _IEEE_)
    32     return __kernel_standard_f (x, x, 126); /*    sqrt(negative) */
    33 
    34   return __ieee754_sqrtf (x);
    35 }
    36 libm_alias_float (__sqrt, sqrt)
    37 #endif
```

As far as I understand from here, if the program doesn’t find a valid implementation for the `sqrt` function from glibc, it calls a hardware function, so a specific machine function, from the kernel. Is this right?
Also, what does `libm_alias_float (__sqrt, sqrt)` mean?

Comment: `libm_alias_float` creates an alias from one function to another. Your understanding is wrong, both `__kernel_standard_f` and `__ieee754_sqrtf` are provided by glibc. One just handles negative numbers (as is required by SVID).

Comment: @Johnas `sysdeps/ieee754/k_standard{,f,l}.c`.

Comment: It's not **that** kernel; not the operating system system kernel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GNU C Library's mathematical functions are fully implemented within the ["glibc" source tree](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git).  They don't rely on the operating system kernel for anything.  The word "kernel" in this context refers to a *computational* kernel — the core of some mathematical algorithm, the part you might want to write in hand-optimized assembly language.

The function `__kernel_standard_f` is badly named.  It contains common code for handling errors in the math functions; it would be better to have named it something like `__math_domain_error`.  In this case, `__sqrtf` calls `__kernel_standard_f` when its argument is negative; `__kernel_standard_f` will then take care of setting `errno` to `EDOM`, possibly calling the SVID [`matherr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/matherr.3.html) callback, and returning a NaN.  (The mysterious code 126 tells `__kernel_standard_f` which function called it and why.  The implementation of `__kernel_standard_f` is in `sysdeps/ieee754/k_standardf.c` and `sysdeps/ieee754/k_standard.c`.)

The condition `_LIB_VERSION != _IEEE_` has to do with whether or not POSIX and/or SVID math error handling is enabled; modern mathematical algorithms would really rather just look for NaN in the result and not have the library waste time setting `errno` or calling `matherr`, so there's a mechanism to turn the latter two off.

If the argument to `__sqrtf` is *not* negative, it tail calls `__ieee754_sqrtf`, which performs the actual calculation of the square root. There are several alternative implementations of this function within the glibc source tree; its generic, C-only version is in `sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_sqrtf.c`.  (The names of the files that implement math functions are cryptic even by glibc's standards.  I don't bother trying to understand them, I just do `find sysdeps -name '*sqrtf*'` or whatever.)  This function *also* starts with logic to detect a negative argument (also zero, infinity, and NaN) and return the appropriate values, but it doesn't touch `errno`.  If you want to understand the mathematical technique used to calculate square roots, this is the file to look at.

If you run the above `find` command yourself you will discover several other files named `e_sqrtf.c`; these are all in directories named after specific CPUs, whose floating-point units have hardware support for computing square roots, so for instance `sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/e_sqrt.c` reads

```
double
__ieee754_sqrt (double x)
{
  double res;

  asm ("sqrtsd %1, %0" : "=x" (res) : "xm" (x));

  return res;
}
```

because the x86 `sqrtsd` instruction does the whole job.

Glibc's build process will select one of these files, instead of the generic C version, when building for one of these CPUs.  This mechanism is complex and not completely documented, but [the "Maintenance" appendix to the glibc manual](https://gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Maintenance.html), particularly its "Source Layout" and "Porting" sections, gives a decent overview of it.

---

`libm_alias_float (__sqrt, sqrt)` arranges for `__sqrtf` to also have the name `sqrtf`, but as a *[weak alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525537/what-are-practical-applications-of-weak-linking)*.  This is necessary for standards compliance.  Please ask a separate question if you want more detail.