# Why is _CrtSetDumpClient not working?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio

I am working on a Windows command-line program written in C using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop.  When compiled in Debug mode, I would really like my program to detect memory leaks and print them on the standard error or standard output so they are in my face.

By calling [_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d41t22sb.aspx), I am able to get memory leak information printed out to the Debug output in Visual Studio (which you can find under the Output pane).  Based on the MSDN documentation, I would think that I can add a call to [_CrtSetDumpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab8sxt5a.aspx) in order to get access to the data being dumped and then print it to stderr.

Here is the code I am using to test this issue:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

void dumpClient(void * userPortion, size_t blockSize)
{
    printf("memory leak: %d\n", blockSize);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    printf("hello\n");
    _CrtSetDumpClient(&dumpClient);
    malloc(44);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

I made a new Visual C++ Win32 Console Application project in Visual Studio, stuck this code into the project, disabled precompiled headers, made sure that the IDE was in Debug mode, and built.  If I run it by pressing F5 (the Start Debugging command), then I can see the following output in the Debug window of Visual Studio, which is good:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
c:\users\david\documents\scraps\test_vc++\testvc\testvc.cpp(15) : {81} normal block at 0x0120A500, 44 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
The program '[3868] TestVC.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

However, if I set a breakpoint inside `dumpClient`, I can see that it is never being called.  Also, if I run the program from a Command Prompt, it just prints `hello`.  The *expected* output that I would hope to see is:

```
hello
memory leak: 44
```

Does anyone know why the `dumpClient` function is not being called at all?

Comment: You created a "normal" leak, not a special one that was tagged as a "client" allocation by your code.  Normal leaks are reported through the _CrtSetReportHook() hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR
You may call `_malloc_dbg(44, _CLIENT_BLOCK, filename, line)` instead of `malloc`.

By looking at dbgheap.c, you can see that the only way your function can be called is there:

```
if (_BLOCK_TYPE(pHead->nBlockUse) == _CLIENT_BLOCK)
{
    _RPT3(_CRT_WARN, "client block at 0x%p, subtype %x, %Iu bytes long.\n",
        (BYTE *)pbData(pHead), _BLOCK_SUBTYPE(pHead->nBlockUse), pHead->nDataSize);

    if (_pfnDumpClient && !__crtIsBadReadPtr(pbData(pHead), pHead->nDataSize))
    {
        (*_pfnDumpClient)((void *)pbData(pHead), pHead->nDataSize);
    }
    else
    {
        _printMemBlockData(plocinfo, pHead);
    }
}
```

So you must have _BLOCK_TYPE(pHead->nBlockUse) == _CLIENT_BLOCK.

When calling `malloc`, you only allocate `_NORMAL_BLOCK`s.

You may call `_malloc_dbg(44, _CLIENT_BLOCK, filename, line)` instead.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/faz3a37z.aspx

Then your function will be called.

Of course Microsoft could have mentionned this in the `_CrtSetDumpClient` documentation, but it would've been too easy ;)

Comment: Thanks!  If I look at crtdbg.h (which comes with Visual Studio) I can see how `malloc(s)` is defined to be `_malloc_dbg(s, _NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)`.  I wonder why they did it that way.  I also see they did something similar with `free(s)`, so I'd probably have to make my own preprocessor macro for malloc and free to get this working properly.

Comment: FYI, dbgheap.c can be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src`

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab8sxt5a.aspx)

```
_CrtSetDumpClient: Installs an application-defined function to 
 dump _CLIENT_BLOCK type memory blocks
```

The keyword here being **_CLIENT_BLOCK**. The various types of [blocks on heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245937(v=vs.60).aspx) are documented here. A simple malloc call creates a **_NORMAL_BLOCK** and hence your function is not called.