# Overloading operator new with a template

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload operator new using templates, but the overloaded function is not getting called.
I am very new to templates, can some one please point me to what I am missing.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    void *p = malloc(size);
    cout <<"I am in template";
    return p;
}

template <typename T>
void* operator new[] (size_t size)
{
    void *p = malloc(size);
    cout <<"I am in template";
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int *a;
    int b;
    a = new int[10];
    cin >> b;
    return 0;
}
```

Changed  and working code is as below(I followed the link mentioned in comment):

```
void * operator new(std::size_t n) throw(std::bad_alloc)
{
    void *p = malloc(n);
    cout <<"I am in template";
    return p;
}
void operator delete(void * p) throw()
{
  //...
}

void *operator new[](std::size_t s) throw(std::bad_alloc)
{
     void *p = malloc(s);
    cout <<"I am in template";
    return p;
}
void operator delete[](void *p) throw()
{
    // TODO: implement
}

int main()
{
    int *a;
    int b;
    a = new int[10];
    cin >> b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new int[]` isn't calling a template, it is defined to call a non-template `operator new[]`.

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186018/how-to-properly-replace-global-new-delete-operators, especially the accepted answer.

Comment: can you please tell me how to call template. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sneda - The code doesn't use the type `T`, so why a template?

Comment: In my project I am trying to write a wrapper for new, in c I had done using macro the same way I want to implement it in c++, if I use a macro, I have to replace wherever new is used, instead I am planning to overload already existing new using global template

Comment: Did you look at my link? It shows you how to do it. Pointless to duplicate this answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks somuch it helped

Comment: I changed the code as mentioned above in my question, how can I implement this using template

Comment: You can't. You have to implement what the standard *tells* you to implement.