# C++ decltype explanation

Tags: c++, decltype

I found the following declaration on StackOverflow to replace the `new` / `delete` operator. But i would like to understand this notation
[How to properly replace global new & delete operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186018/how-to-properly-replace-global-new-delete-operators)

```
void * operator new(decltype(sizeof(0)) n) noexcept(false)
```

Now let's split up: New obviusly needs to return a Pointer. And `new` is used as an operator. So far so good. It is also clear to me the `n` must represent the number of bytes to allocate.
The unclear part is the argument:

`sizeof(0)` (on a 32bit machine) evaluates to `sizeof(int) = 4`
Then I got `decltype(4 n)`??? 
What does this mean?

Comment: You misread the parentheses, the `decltype` only encapsulates the `sizeof`, the `n` is just a function parameter name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decltype(sizeof(0)) n` does not mean `decltype(4 n)`.  In

```
void * operator new(decltype(sizeof(0)) n) noexcept(false)
```

the `decltype(sizeof(0)) n` part means the parameter is named `n` and it has the type of what `sizeof(0)` returns.  You could replace this with

```
void * operator new(std::size_t n) noexcept(false)
```

since `sizeof` is guaranteed to return a `std::size_t` per [[expr.sizeof]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.sizeof#6) but doing it the first way means you don't need to include `<cstddef>`

Answer (score 1):

`n` needs a type.

The type is deduced by `decltype(sizeof(0))`.

`sizeof(0)` evaluates to a value of `4` but its type is `std::size_t`. It's as if you had used

```
std::size_t s = sizeof(0);
using type = decltype(s); // Only the type is important here, not the value.
void * operator new(type n) noexcept(false)
```