# Why the overriden `operator new` isn't called?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, operator-overloading, new-operator

I run the following code in VS2005:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <new>
#include <stdlib.h>

int flag = 0;

void* my_alloc(std::size_t size)
{
    flag = 1;
    return malloc(size);
}

void* operator new(std::size_t size) { return my_alloc(size); }
void operator delete(void* ptr) { free(ptr); }
void* operator new[](std::size_t size) { return my_alloc(size); }
void operator delete[](void* ptr) { free(ptr); }

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    std::cout << str;
    return flag;
}
```

I enter a long enough string (longer than the small-string-optimization buffer):

```
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
```

In a Debug compilation the process returns 1, in Release configuration the process returns 0, which means that the `new` operator isn't called! I can verify this by putting a breakpoint, writing to output/debug output, etc...

Why is this, and is it a standard conforming behavior?

Comment: Did you try debugging and stepping through the code instead of relying on the output?

Comment: @Kolky: yes. For example I set a global flag in `operator new` and returned it from main a -- solution with no output at all.

Comment: There's an [interesting bug in GCC <= 4.6.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629270/how-does-stdstring-allocate-memory-in-gcc-with-fwhole-program) in which under certain compiler settings, `string`'s allocator would *not* use the replaced allocation functions. So this isn't entirely unheard of. For fun, try a different data structure, like a `vector`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Interesting. Yes, I know it works with vector. It's indeed a bug. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research, what @bart-jan wrote in their other answer (now deleted) is in fact correct.

As it can be easily seen mine operator isn't called in Release at all, instead the CRT version is called. (And no, for all those who shot in the dark, there's no recursion here.) The question is "why"?

The above was compiled against the dynamically linked CRT (which is the default). Microsoft provides an instantiation of `std::string` (among many other standard templates) within the CRT DLL. Looking into Dinkumware's headers shipped with VS2005:

```
#if defined(_DLL_CPPLIB) && !defined(_M_CEE_PURE)

template class _CRTIMP2_PURE allocator<char>;
// ...
template class _CRTIMP2_PURE basic_string<char, char_traits<char>,
    allocator<char> >;
```

Where `_CRTIMP2_PURE` expands to `__declspec(dllimport)`. That means that in Release the linker links the `std::string` to the version that was instantiated when the CRT was built, which uses the default implementation of `new`.

It's unclear why it doesn't happen in debug. As @Violet Giraffe guessed correctly it must be affected by some switches. However, I think it's the linker switches, not the compiler switches. I can't determine exactly which switch matters.

The remaining question which other answers ignored is "is it standard"? Trying the code in VS2010, it indeed called my `operator new` no matter what configuration I compile! Looking at the headers shipped with VS2010 it reveals that Dinkumware *removed* the `__declspec(dllimport)` for the above instantiation. Thus, I believe the old behavior is indeed a compiler bug, and *not* standard.

Comment: It sounds like it's sort of a linker/library bug, by which the default versions of the functions aren't allowed to be replaced conditionally. GCC calls this "weak reference"; MSVC must have a similar notion.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Not exactly. You just cannot do it in context of DLLs. The DLL that contains the std::string implementation is already linked with some `new` implementation, you can't rebind it later when it's loaded by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Calling cout << std::string() from your new operator or one of the called functions within, will cause unpredicable program behavour. Don't use io from your new operator. Doing things like that may re-enter your new operator.

Comment: std::ostream << (const char *) may also call into operator new!

Comment: @Violet: I didn't. `const char*` is not an `std::string`.

Comment: @bert-jan: first I think it can't according to standard. Second, the results are reproducible even without any output at all.

Comment: If you instatiate std::string() or use std::cout << (...) operator new() will be re-entered, unless the std RTL is used as a program extention (such as windows DLLs).

Comment: Maybe the std::string assosiated allocator decides not to use new() in release versions in this case, but that's a far guess

Answer (score 0):

You really should debug the code step-by-step. Did you try setting /Od in your release configuration to disable optimization? I wonder if that changes the behaviour.

Comment: Tried it. It doesn't change anything. Same as above.

Comment: @ybungalobill: OK, how about linking to debug runtime? Try /MDd instead of /MD. Besides, you can now try stepping into the code to see which function intercepts the control. Maybe, there's some macro, that is defined only in release?

Comment: debug libraries in release with no optimizations: same result.

Comment: @ybungalobill: And what do you see when stepping into `new`?

Comment: Hmmm, my new is just isn't being compiled in when in release. +1 for the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

You have infinite recursion.

Instead, do like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <new>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* my_alloc( char const* str, std::size_t size )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "%s %lu\n", str, (unsigned long)size );
    return malloc( size ); // I don't care for errors here
}

void* operator new( std::size_t size )      { return my_alloc( "new", size ); }
void operator delete( void* ptr )           { free(ptr); }
void* operator new[]( std::size_t size )    { return my_alloc( "new[]", size ); }
void operator delete[]( void* ptr )         { free( ptr ); }

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "? ";
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    std::cout << str;
}
```

Comment: The same result. See the edit above for a version with no recursion (and I don't have recursion anyway).

Comment: I did check it, with Visual C++ 10. It's marginally possible that you're up against a compiler bug *in addition* to your own original bug. But I consider that highly unlikely; most likely is PEBCAK.

Comment: Please explain to me where you see recursion in the second code snippet. I don't see/observe recursion in the first snipped either, btw.

Comment: The (possible) infinite recursion is in your original code, not the second snippet. For the second snippet consider that you're most probably 'doing something wrong. Like running the wrong exe, whatever. The problem with the second code did not reproduce with Visual C++ 10.0

Comment: I'm going to check it as soon as I get to a computer with VS2010.

Comment: One way that you can end up running the wrong exe is when compilation fails for some reason, and just leaves the old exe around. To avoid that possibility, delete all exe files before trying.

Comment: Alf: You're right that VS2010 behaves correctly. It's indeed an implementation bug, see my answer. You were just shooting in the dark like most people here; there isn't any recursion at all.

Comment: @ybungalobill: There was in the original code, though it was subtle.  The calls to `cout` could call `operator new`.