# C++ / Windows: Replacing global new works, new[] doesn't

Tags: c++, windows, overriding, new-operator

I just started playing around with overriding global new/delete (purely for educational purposes) and was having an issue.

I'm using a fairly mature project of mine to test with several k loc. First thing I did was override `new` and `new[]` to simply use `malloc` and increment a static counter. `new` seems to work fine but I noticed that my `new` gets called by the crt version of `new[]` from `newaop.cpp` which looks like so:

```
void *__CRTDECL operator new[](size_t count) _THROW1(std::bad_alloc)
{   // try to allocate count bytes for an array
    return (operator new(count));
}
```

My version is

```
void* operator new[](size_t count)
{
    // malloc and whatnot
}
```

The `new[]` is called by some stl functions. My versions are in a .h/.cpp file which is the first include in every other file in the project.

I didn't have much time to try and figure out why this morning, but I would love it if someone could explain why my version is not being called.

Edit: build is debug/x86, I don't remember the stl container (not at home) but probably `map`.

Comment: Can you verify from what STL container is it called and What configuration do you build?

Comment: build is debug/x86, I don't remember the stl container (not at home) but probably map.

Comment: For replacing allocation logic inside containers it's better to use a different allocator than overriding `new`.

Comment: I realise that, I was basically just playing around (is it good or bad that that's my idea of entertainment :) but I'm wondering why my new is called but my new[] is not - the crt version gets called, which in turn calls my new.

Comment: @carpat: [I think I know the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257236/why-the-overrided-operator-new-isnt-call), but I wish to be sure. You must provide more details. `map` will not call `new[]` anyway since it uses the default allocator that uses plain `new`.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Yeah those linker switches look like a likely culprit, I'll have to wait until I get home to dig into it though.

Comment: I declared it *exactly* as you posted and it worked for me. Also - I think you don't need to #include the file with your version in every other file. It just has to be in any translation unit and it 'overrides' the original and can be used everywhere in the project (very much a special case).

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like: `char* p = new char[100]; delete[] p;`
and put a breakpoint and see what happens.